# Change font-size on mouse over, revert to original on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that changes the font-size of an element when the mouse enters it, and revert it back to its original font-size when the mouse leaves it. This is what I have:

```
   $(".month").hover(function(){

        var size = $(this).css("font-size");

        $(this).stop().animate({
            fontSize: start_font + font_off,
            opacity: '1'
        }, 200);    

    },function(){

        $(this).stop().animate({
            fontSize: size,
            opacity: '1'
        }, 200);
    });
```

It changes the font size on mouse in, but when the mouse leaves, it just stays the same size. (I did an alert(size) after the font-size change, and it holds the correct value.) What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What are start_font , font_off

Comment: Why not use CSS3 transitions and let it degrade gracefully?

Comment: I put var start_font = 50;
var font_off = 8; at the top of page (outside the function)

Comment: That means default font size is 50..??

Comment: @elclanrs I'm trying to practice with jQuery.

Comment: @Gautam3164 It would actually be 58

Comment: @Andy see my other answer thats more code but u can easily understand...

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this easily with CSS:

```
.month:hover {
  font-size: 150%;
  }
```

However, in jquery you can do:

```
$(".month").hover(function(){
  $(this).
    stop().
    animate({
      fontSize: "5em"
      }, 1000);
  },
  function(){
    $(this).
      stop().
      animate({
        fontSize: "1em"
        }, 1000);
    }
  );
```

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgqKM/). Note, I've used `ems` since `The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt.` [Source](http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in javascript? The .month elements' font-sizes dynamically change (using javascript) and I would like to keep everything in one place. Also, I'm trying to learn javascript, so it'd be helpful

Comment: The problem is that the elements of .month all have different sizes, so the only way to get their size (from what I understand) is to do .css().

Comment: See the last edit I made, the line about `ems`. Does it work for your case?

Comment: Well the original sizes of each element are all different. Your example with ems reverts all the elements to the same size when they should instead revert back to the size they were originally. For example if there were 3 elements with sizes 10, 20, 30px, they should all resize to 58px on mouse enter, but then revert back to 10, 20, and 30px respectively on mouse leave.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand this will help you

```
$(".month").hover(function(){

    var size = $(this).css("font-size");

    $(this).stop().animate({
        fontSize: start_font + font_off,
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);    

},function(){
    var size = $(this).css("font-size");      //Add this
    $(this).stop().animate({
        fontSize: size - font_off,   
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);
});
```

or through the css you can do with :hover like

```
.month:hover {
   font-size: 150%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(".month").hover(function(){
    var size = $(this).css("font-size");
    alert(size); 
   $(this).stop().animate({
        fontSize: start_font + font_off,
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);    

},function(){

    $(this).stop().animate({
        fontSize: size,//In this line u r getting error as size not defined 
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);
    alert('leaving '+size);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

**From Jquery animate function:**

```
$('#my-list li').hover(function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ fontSize : '20px' });
},
function() {
      $(this).stop().animate({ fontSize : '12px' });
});
```

**And From CSS**

```
a{
    font-size:16px;
}

a:hover {
    font-size:18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".month").hover(function(){

 if($('#month').hasClass('hoverout')){

   $(this).removeClass("hoverout");
 }

   $(this).addClass("hoverin");
   $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);    

},function(){

     if($('#month').hasClass('hoverin')){

            $(this).removeClass("hoverin");
      }

     $(this).addClass("hoverout");

    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 200);

});
```

css

```
.hoverin{

   font-size:20px;
}
```

.hoverout{

```
  font-size:50px;

 }
```